# Joomla 3.1 - Get active menu item url

Tags: joomla

As soon as I click on the "Media" item in my main menu, the following url is generated:

http://test.local/index.php/media-files

Now, I would like to create a module that is displayed only in media-files. Moreover, I want to retrieve the url of this active menu item.

So my question: How can I get the SEF-URL of an active menu item?

Thanks in advance,

enne

Comment: Can you share some code, a fiddle or a live link?

Comment: Yes, the page is accessable via http://vz197.webdynamite4u.com 
Unfortunately, the content of the media section has not been deployed yet. As I said, I just want to retrieve the url of my active menu item. 
E.g. if I enter http://vz197.webdynamite4u.com/index.php/media-files in my webbrowser, I would like to retrieve this url in my module that is activated in the media section. I'm no Joomla expert but I'm sure this should be possible.

Comment: You don't just want to take the jinput preoperties? why do you want the sef url and not the request data?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->link;

echo JRoute::_($menu);
```

I've tested this as well, so let me know if it's what you require.