# Joomla get menu item id

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a component that has a simple payment form. I just want to get the current menu item id. I've tried several things to get the id.

```
    //get the active menu item id
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu   = $app->getMenu();
    $active   = $menu->getActive();
    $activeId = $active->id;
    JLog::add('active id is: '.$activeId); //I get nothing returned

    $currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
    JLog::add('menu id is: '.$currentMenuId); //I get nothing returned

    //try to see what the current url is
    $currenturl = JURI::current();
    JLog::add('current url is: '.$currenturl); //I get mysite.com/index.php
```

I use `$activeId` code in my plugins without problems but it doesn't work in my component. What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;
echo $menu;
```

Hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks but that is the same as my question just a different way to write it. I tried it anyways and I still get nothing returned.

Comment: Try `var_dump($menu)` and see what get's displayed. Also, on the payment form, is the does the URl end in */index.php* ?

Comment: `var_dump($menu)` gives the big list of menus including the one I want. The URI doesn't have index.php. The whole URI of the comment is `http://mysite.com/step2bv`. I want to get the id or name of step2bv for further processing.

Comment: Hmm how odd. Have you edited any core Joomla files? Try this and see what you get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005478/joomla-3-1-get-active-menu-item-url/19013385#19013385

Comment: No core Joomla files edited. Tried the code and get nothing for `$url`. I don't get it.

Comment: Is it a custom component or one from JED? If a custom one, I would be more than happy to take a look to see what the issue is

Comment: Yes custom. It is a dev site but I can send by other means if your willing to look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38240/discussion-between-lodder-and-tom)

Comment: Thanks to @Lodder. I had this code in the controller. That is not where the menu is. So that can't work! Just move this code to the view and that's it.