# Joomla 3 Hide Content from specific page

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, joomla3.0

I am looking to hide a div on some pages that is appearing on all the pages. I have used some php and css to assign each page with a unique code but I cannot get the correct css to hide or remove the div from those pages.

```
 .pageid111 .logo{
   display: none;
  }
```

is what I am attempting to use. Would appreciate any help

Comment: What's do you mean with "from a specific page"? 
Are you trying to hide the logo from the home page?

Comment: Well yes. I have the logo on the home page but do not want it to appear on the about us page

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Specifically, what does the line of HTML where your PHP assigns each page a unique code look like? It would probably be easier putting a homepage class on your body element in your home page's html.

Comment: A link to a copy of the live website would probably elicit some more definitive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly calling logo in all files, you can create a module and display it wherever needed. You have to change some codes in template files. I will give an example so you can do it for your own template.

If you see the default template protostar that comes with Joomla. it has a file named index.php. There $logo is defined at line number 67-78 as

```
// Logo file or site title param
if ($this->params->get('logoFile'))
{
    $logo = '<img src="' . JUri::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile') . '" alt="' . $sitename . '" />';
}
elseif ($this->params->get('sitetitle'))
{
    $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="' . $sitename . '">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitetitle')) . '</span>';
}
else
{
    $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="' . $sitename . '">' . $sitename . '</span>';
}
```

You can comment this out.

Next on the same file little below around line 140 you will find this code

```
<?php echo $logo; ?>
```

This code is calling the logo file. Just replace this code with

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" style="xhtml" />
```

You have just added a new module position with name logo.

This will not reflect until you add this position in the `templateDetails.xml` file

if you open that file you will find these lines

```
<positions>
        <position>banner</position>
        <position>debug</position>
        <position>position-0</position>
        <position>position-1</position>
        .............
</positions>
```

Add logo position to that

```
<positions>
        <position>banner</position>
        <position>debug</position>
        <position>logo</position>
        <position>position-0</position>
        <position>position-1</position>
        .............
</positions>
```

So you now have a extra module position in place of hardcoded logo image. You can put any image module there or just create an html module.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be detect the home page using the joomla framework
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Through the same getMenu() method you can generalize your code for the other menu items
[Joomla 3.1 - Get active menu item url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005478/joomla-3-1-get-active-menu-item-url)